# PHP , explode data from file

Tags: php, explode

I encountered a problem during exploding data from file.
My file looks like

> 04-21-1991    9:09    58  10004-21-1991   9:09    33  00904-21-1991   9:09    34  01304-21-1991   17:08   62  11904-21-1991   17:08   33  00704-21-1991

I'd like to explode data from it like

04-21-1991  9:09    58  100

04-21-1991  9:09    33  009

04-21-1991  9:09    34  013

04-21-1991  17:08   62  119

04-21-1991  17:08   33  007

what i did till now is obtaining an array ( numbers are different, becouse file is different, but structure is the same)

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(901) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "07-21-1990"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "06:43"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "58"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "202
07-21-1990"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "07:03"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "33"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "4
07-21-1990"
```

and here is my code

```
header("Content-type:text/plain");
  $file = fopen("data/data-03", "r");

$result = array();
    $file = explode("   ", file_get_contents("data/data-03"));
    foreach ( $file as $content ) 
        {
            $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("    ", $content)));
        }
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: use [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead of explode() if each element should be the same size

Comment: Explode by " " and then iterate the result and assign the values to your array

Comment: pay more attention to bring clear input and clear output, corresponding, well indented etc. This is horrible.

Comment: For structural assertion, grouping by that, and if your input contains varied spacing you may wish to use `preg_match_all` instead of a crude explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using `preg_match_all()`.  Like so:

```
<?php
$string = "04-21-1991 9:09 58 10004-21-1991 9:09 33 00904-21-1991 9:09 34 01304-21-1991 17:08 62 11904-21-1991 17:08 33 00704-21-1991";

preg_match_all("/([\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}\s[\d]*:[\d]{2}\s[\d]{2}\s[\d]{3})/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

The above code will output:

```
Array ( [0] => 04-21-1991 9:09 58 100 [1] => 04-21-1991 9:09 33 009 [2] => 04-21-1991 9:09 34 013 [3] => 04-21-1991 17:08 62 119 [4] => 04-21-1991 17:08 33 007 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code of doing that, assuming your initial data format won't change.

```
$str = "04-21-1991 9:09 58 100 04-21-1991 9:09 33 009 04-21-1991 9:09 34 013 04-21-1991    17:08 62 119 04-21-1991 17:08 33 007 04-21-1991";

$result = array();
$result = explode(" ",$str);
$row = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result)-1; ){
    $arr[$row]["date"] = $result[$i++];
    $arr[$row]["hour"] = $result[$i++];
    $arr[$row]["num"] = $result[$i++];
    $arr[$row]["num2"] = $result[$i++];
    $row++;
}

//check some data:
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ){
    echo $arr[$i]["date"] . " ";
    echo $arr[$i]["hour"] . " ";
    echo $arr[$i]["num"] . " ";
    echo $arr[$i]["num2"] . " ";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also process the exploded array in the following way:

```
$out = array();

for ( $i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if ( floor($i / 4) == ($i / 4))
        $out[ floor($i / 4) ] = $result[$i];
    $out[ floor($i / 4) ] .= ' '.$result[$i]; 
}
```

you could replace ' ' with the seperator you want, I assumed a simple space.

It is basicly always concatenating  4 entries of the array resulting from your explosion, and adds them to a new array. You could also fetch the results in a new String and just add a \n after every 4th entry in the same way, if that is what you desire.

Comment: All answers are very handfull, but Your the most. Thank You